# Twilio Client SDK for Android - Echo Cancellation?

Tags: android, voip, twilio

What about the echo cancellation in Twilio Client for Android?

Is it included? Or something needs to be developed on a lower level?

Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big variance in the behavior of different hardware/brands of mobile phones. I suggest you test at least few brands before you make a conclusion. In any case, I would not recommend on developing an AEC for android from scratch - you would quickly find out that this is a very difficult task.